# Angular Attribute Always Undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, angularjs

I am trying to bind the css class using angularjs function. It's working properly but It always printing so many error on browser console. can you please any help me on this matter??. I have attached my code and screenshot below.

```
 <tr ng-repeat-start="inventory in inventoryDetails.HotelFareInventoryAllotmentDetails">
                                <td  rowspan="2">{{inventory.HotelRoomCategoryName}}</td>
                                <td>Inventory</td>
                                <td ng-class="getClassName(1)">{{inventory.D1.Inventory}}</td>
                                <td ng-class="getClassName(2)">{{inventory.D2.Inventory}}</td>
                                <td ng-class="getClassName(3)">{{inventory.D3.Inventory}}</td>
                 {{inventory.D31.Inventory}}</td>                              
                            </tr>
                            <tr ng-repeat-end>
                                <td>CutOff</td>
                                <td ng-class="{{getClassName(1}})">{{inventory.D1.Cutoff}}</td>
                                <td ng-class="getClassName(2)">{{inventory.D2.Cutoff}}</td>
                                <td  ng-class="getClassName(3)">{{inventory.D3.Cutoff}}</td>

                            </tr>
```

---

```
  $scopeChild.getClassName = function (dayID) {

                                var dayIndex = parseInt(dayID) - 1;
                                if ($scopeChild.Days[dayIndex].IsWeekend) {
                                    return 'weekend';
                                }
                                else {
                                    return '';
                                }



                        }
```

[image]

Comment: Pleae check your $scopeChild.Days arr length and dayIndex value

Comment: the values are ok, It's working properly, but only in browser console It showing so many errors

Comment: From where u r getting $scopeChild.Days Array? And in html you made a syntactic mistake in line  <td ng-class="{{getClassName(1}})">{{inventory.D1.Cutoff}}</td>

Comment: Please create plunker

Comment: add condition to check dayIndex should not null and $scopeChild.Days array length should not zero.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the error I can see that `$scopeChild` exists and has a member called `Days`. However, `$scopeChild.Days[dayIndex]` is `undefined`. As a result, `IsWeekend` is obviously not an existent property of your `undefined` object. As a result, you get the error. There are two cases:

- you might want to make sure that `$scopeChild.Days[dayIndex]` will exist whenever you call this function, by fixing the logic of your code
- you might want to make sure that the error will not happen, even if the `function` is called in the wrong way

If you want to write a library, then you need an idiot-proof solution, but if the problem lies in your algorithm, then you need to rethink it. For instance, if one looks at `dayID`, he/she should realize that the values of `dayID` should be either between 0..6 or 1..7. What is the ID of Monday in your case? Are you sure that the parameter `dayID` is always numeric? No trailing white characters? Is that number existent in `Days`? Etc., etc. I bet your problem is that the algorithm is flawed and I suggest that you should debug. Example:

```
  $scopeChild.getClassName = function (dayID) {

                                var dayIndex = parseInt(dayID) - 1;
                                if (!$scopeChild.Days[dayIndex]) {
                                    dayIndex = "Busted..."; //put a breakpoint here and see what happens
                                    return;
                                }
                                if ($scopeChild.Days[dayIndex].IsWeekend) {
                                    return 'weekend';
                                }
                                else {
                                    return '';
                                }



                        }
```

Also, as vkrishna already pointed out, you have a syntax error, that is, you close a paranthesis which was not opened. And finally, it is advisable to paste the error into the question instead of attaching it as an image.

Answer (score 0):

Quick and dirty solution :

```
if ($scopeChild.Days && $scopeChild.Days[dayIndex] && $scopeChild.Days[dayIndex].IsWeekend){}
```

You may need this specially if your data are loaded asynchronously.

If you're interested about to push more the investigation i'll need to see your whole controller definition.

Comment: @Grundy as i said i can't give more without more information. And i learned to not get too much headache with javascript when it wasn't needed :P, another test would be to check if dayIndex is in the range of the array but it's still checking errors a bit late.